# Check if dictionary contains substring?

Tags: c#, string, dictionary, string-parsing

Say I have two dictionaries with the following key value pairs:

```
1, "Hello"
2, "Example"
```

And another dictionary as follows:

```
1, "HelloWorld"
2, "Example2"
```

I want to find out if these dictionaries contain the substring "hello" within them.  
`dictionary.ContainsValue("Hello")` will work for the first example but not the second one.  How can I check for existence of a substring in all values in a dictionary?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just use `Any` to to check for the first Value that contains "Hello"

```
dictionary.Any(kvp=>kvp.Value.Contains("Hello"))
```

Comment: It's not recognizing the 'Any' function.

Comment: Make sure you add `using System.Linq;`.

Comment: This needs to check _every_ dictionary element, so any performance gain of Dictionary will be neglected.

Comment: @user626528 wrong, `Any` check for the first value that matches the predicate.

Comment: Worked great! thanks, its gonna be another 7 minutes before I can mark this as the answer but I will.

Comment: @juharr, the same if you use plain list to lookup in.

Comment: @john hannigan, this works if you don't care about performance at all.

Comment: @user626528 And exactly how would you make this preform better?

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary doesn't allow to search for substrings. To find it, you need to enumerate all values and check each for substring, as suggested by juharr. However, this method is highly inefficient. Use it only if you don't care about search performance at all.
If you need good performance, use suffix array algorithm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array

Comment: This seems like overkill and wouldn't work for finding "Hello" in "HelloWorld" because "Hello" isn't a suffix in that case.

Comment: @juharr, this might be overkill if TS doesn't care about performance, but you obviously don't understand what is suffix array algorithm. It always finds _any_ substrings.

Comment: Clearly you should explain what suffix array algorithm is and how it works.

Comment: @scenia, the referenced Wikipedia article contains all information about suffix array you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
dictionary.Values.Any(v => v.Contains("Hello"));
```

Dictionary isn't an IEnumerable itself so it won't have LINQ extensions apply to it.

Comment: Dictionary is an `IEnumerable` of `KeyValuePairs`